# Which data type use for column representing Enum?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

In my DB I have a column named `type`.
In my model package there is an Enum of CREDIT, DEBIT, SAVINGS

My table can have billions of records.
The colum type has to be indexed.

I am using MySQL 5.6

And using JPA for persistency.

My question is: ***what data type should I use for such column?***

I am thinking bout: integer or string.

If my column is int I will use `EnumType.ordinal` otherwise `EnumType.string`.

Now which data type is better in case of performance for:

- searching based on this key
- and to do some join?

Should I use int or string, or maybe there is some better third option?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `INTEGER` column if your database does not support enum types directly, since using a string type takes more space and is more difficult computationally to search.

Postgres supports user-defined enums, which the database itself will map into integers internally, and you can use `EnumType.STRING` with a Postgres backend. This has the advantages of enumerated types, such as easier human reading and range checking. I'm not familiar with what capabilities MySQL has in this regard.

Comment: Aren't enums in databases considered bad practise?

Answer (score 1):

Integers are faster than varchars, and allow sorting in the database using the natural enum ordering. But the readability suffers: 0 is less clear than 'CREDIT' when you look at rows in the database.

If sorting doesn't matter, I would first measure if the performance and space gains are worth the readability loss, and then choose accordingly. Remember that with only 3 different values and such a huge amount of rows, you'd better search on another indexed column first, that divides the amount of rows to look at by much more than 3.

Comment: Is it really necessary to see 'CREDIT' when looking directly at a table's content?

Comment: Necessary, no. Easier to understand than 0, yes.

Comment: Using a string just to make it a little easier to understand seems like an overkill to me.